# SVG still not appearing after adding mime type

Tags: asp.net, svg, iis-7

I am trying to display an svg image.

When I display the svg image with the below code is does not display.

```
<img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="Logo">
```

I also tried this syntax, but then it downloads instead of displaying.

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="/img/logo.svg" />
```

I have already set the mime type to image/svg+xml in web.config.

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <remove fileExtension=".svgz" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

It appears to be seeing the file type as application/octet-stream even though I have defined it at image/svg+xml.  I am running and ASP.NET site with IIS 7.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem and my web.config syntax for the mime type looks slightly different to yours.

This:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension="svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

is all I added and it fixed the problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried your code so that the fileExtension excluded the period, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: I also tried this but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your web config:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
        <handlers>
            <add name="SVG Handler" path="*.svg" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to .htaccess file (at the root), add this line of code:

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
```